# How to change settings with Uploadify after control has already been created

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I initialize Uploadify using the following code:

```
$('#file1').uploadifive({
   'buttonClass': 'upload-btn',
   'uploadScript': '/Upload/',
   'fileObjName': 'files',
   'fileType': 'text/xml',
   'formData': { 'uploadType': 'Crew' },
   'onUploadComplete': function(file, data) {
      var results = $.parseJSON(data);
      if (results.error) {
         var info = file.queueItem.find('span.fileinfo');
         if (info) info.text(' - ' + results.error);
         return;
      }

      window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Upload/Checkdata/")' + results.id;
   }
});
```

This works, however I need to modify the `formData` property when a radio checkbox changes.  So, I've tried this:

```
$('input[name=UploadType]:radio').change(function () {
   $('#file1').uploadifive({ 'formData': this.value });
});
```

However, when that code runs, it breaks the Uploadify control (it now no longer uploads anywhere).  I'm guessing because it completely *re-initializes* the control with all new settings.

How can I update just this one setting?  I've read the Uploadify docs and none of them say anything about updating settings; just initializing and calling methods.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out one solution, but not sure if it's the right way to do things (i.e., it might break in future versions of Uploadify).

Basically, it appears you can keep a reference to your configuration around, and update that object at any time:

```
var uploadifySettings = {
   'buttonClass': 'upload-btn',
   'uploadScript': '/Upload/',
   'fileObjName': 'files',
   'fileType': 'text/xml',
   'formData': { 'uploadType': 'Crew' },
   'onUploadComplete': function(file, data) {
      var results = $.parseJSON(data);
      if (results.error) {
         var info = file.queueItem.find('span.fileinfo');
         if (info) info.text(' - ' + results.error);
         return;
      }

      window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Upload/Checkdata/")' + results.id;
   }
}

$('input[name=UploadType]:radio').change(function () {
   uploadifySettings.formData.uploadType = this.value;
});

$('#file1').uploadifive(uploadifySettings);
```